# Psych package error with autoR() function: Error in apply(x[1:(n.obs - lag), ], 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm): dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: r, psych

This is a follow up to my last question I posted. Someone did find a working solution, or so it seemed. It looked as if the code ran as expected, but I'm a bit dubious now.

I have a dataframe

```
data <- structure(list(study_id = structure(c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 
1003, 1003), format.spss = "F6.0", display_width = 0L), Date = structure(c(18584, 
18584, 18585, 18585, 18585, 18585), format.spss = "DATE11", display_width = 0L, class = "Date"), 
    SignalNumber = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L), 
    NegativeAffect = structure(c(1, 2.25, 1.5, 1, 2.25, 1.5), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L), 
    PositiveAffect = structure(c(4.33333333333333, 2, 2.66666666666667, 
    3.33333333333333, 3, 4), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L), 
    Date_first = structure(c(18584, 18584, 18584, 18584, 18584, 
    18584), format.spss = "DATE11", display_width = 0L, class = "Date"), 
    ID_day = structure(c(1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Initially, I wanted to use the `autoR()` function in `psych` grouping PositiveAffect and NegativeAffect by study_id.

```
library(psych)
autoR(data$NegativeAffect, group=data$study_id, lag=1, na.rm=TRUE) #original method which gave error
autoR(data[,c(4, 5)],group=datat$study_id, lag=1, na.rm=TRUE) #suggested method which does run
```

So, great, the line of code from the suggestion runs. However, I am also interested in grouping with a different variable called ID_day.

I tried to use the suggested method:

```
autoR(data[,c(4, 5)],group=ema_affect$ID_day, lag=1, na.rm=TRUE) #gives error
```

I get the same error I initially got when I was writing the syntax with the `$` operator: Error in apply(x[1:(n.obs - lag), ], 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm): dim(X) must have a positive length

I'm now not sure if the solution is actually running the function as intended.

As the user mentioned in my previous post, there is little documentation about this which makes it difficult for me to study up on and fix it. The RDocumentation on the package doesn't seem to go into detail about this specific error...but maybe I'm missing something.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: I've tried rearranging my dataframe columns and removing any columns I don't need. I ensured that every column that needs to be numeric is. This error is also keeping me from changing the lags if I ever needed to since this would be the group I want to run analyses on for daily level ratings.

Comment: I think there's a bug in `autoR` in lines 20, 21 where a `drop=FALSE` is missing in the `apply`—a popular mistake. Seems, currently the function doesn't like vectors, but this works (if enough nobs per group): `psych::autoR(data[4:5], group=data$study_id, lag=1, na.rm=TRUE)`. The data provided has too few observations per group (two where you probably need about ten, but I'm not sure. I used `data <- data[sample(nrow(data), 36, replace=TRUE), ]`). You should notify the author about the bug (I'm not familiar with the function, though, so do this only if you're sure you haven't misused it).

Comment: I should mention that my full dataset goes into about 300 observations, about 11 observations per person per day (multiple days, with multiple ratings per day) which is why I'm also interested in grouping by ```ID_day``` so I can run autocorrelation only on ratings for a specific day. If I posted my full dataset, I would have no other room to post! Do you know of another method I could post the dataset without using ```dput``` so I can post the larger set? Other than that, I'm certain I'm using the function correctly. I'm essentially emulating the analyses from another paper. I'll report it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to AcidCatfish.  That bug has been fixed and the new release will  be on the pmc server tomorrow.  (To get the latest version of psych `install.packages("psych", repos= "https://personality-project.org/r,type="source")`

Comment: Sorry.  That link wasn't quite right;         "install.packages("psych", repos= "https://personality-project.org/r" ,type="source")